# How to answer this question involving integrating separable equation?

Tags: integration, derivatives

Help appreciated on the linked [question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zVNdy.jpg). Thanks! :-)

Here's my [working out]

[working out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BF5rq.jpg)

Comment: Please use mathJax to typeset your question

Comment: Your question is not intelligible.

Comment: how do i use mathJax?

Comment: First of all, if you want other people to make an effort to help you, make an effort first -- typeset your question well. Anyways, your mistake: there's no such integration "rule" that "$\int\frac{dt}{\text{whatever}}=\ln(\text{whatever})$".

Comment: the question was how to use mathJax. Fyi im new to this forum and asking how to use clearly demonstrates the effort made :-) Also the integral of say f(x) . dx is ln(x) + c.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By separating variables we get:
$$ \frac{dN}{N-N^2/M} = (\alpha+\beta \cos(t) ) dt$$
$$ \int \frac{dN}{N-N^2/M} = \int (\alpha+\beta \cos(t) ) dt$$
$$ \log(N)-\log(N-M) = \alpha t + \beta \sin(t) + C $$
$$ \log(N-M)-\log(N) = - \alpha t - \beta \sin(t) - C $$
So

$$ \frac{(N-M)}{N} = e^{-\alpha t -\sin(t) - C} $$

Evaluating at $ t = 0 , N(0) = N_0 $, so

$$ \frac{N_0-M}{N_0} = e^{-C} $$

$$ C = \log(\frac{ N_0}{N_0-M}) $$

$$ \frac{(N-M)}{N} = e^{-\alpha t -\sin(t)} \frac{N_0-M}{N_0} $$

$$ 1-\frac{M}{N} = e^{-\alpha t -\sin(t)} \frac{N_0-M}{N_0} $$

$$ N = \frac{M}{1- e^{-\alpha t -\sin(t)} \frac{N_0-M}{N_0}} $$

$$ N = \frac{N_0 M}{N_0- e^{-\alpha t -\sin(t)} (N_0-M)}  = \frac{N_0 M}{N_0+ e^{-\alpha t -\sin(t)} (M-N_0)} $$

which is the answer from the question.

Comment: Does this involve partial fractions?